# Как спарсить тэг с двойным классом?

Tags: java, dom, jsoup, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div.row"); - работает
Elements elements = doc.select("div.column.one-fourth"); - работает
Elements elements = doc.select("ul.showhide.rasp4"); - не работает
```

Почему последння строчка кода не работает? Ничего не выдает.
Пробовал писать еще вот так:

```
Elements resultLinks = doc.select("div.column.one-fourth > ul.showhide.rasp4"); // direct a after ul
```

Тоже без результатов. Вопрос: как парсить тэг с двойным классом и после определенного класса? (Документацию читаю по возможности, прошу туда не посылать, а привести пример, желательно по моему вложенному скриншоту)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul[class*="showhide"][class*="rasp4"]
```

Можно сделать более строгую выборку через регулярные выражения ("~" вместо "*") , чтобы он не захватывал **префикс**showhide**суфикс**. Но это уже дело хозяина.
Вот [ссылка](http://try.jsoup.org/~NOjKpjS97i7Zt8mJP2JScSCZ-tM) с подобным примером

Comment: А не подскажете как найти тэг после определенного тэга?

Comment: [не ленись](http://try.jsoup.org/~ox2GhLpt2wJB-QvJmZxMD4M1_C8)

Comment: Спасибо!
Документацию значит плохо читаю, т.к. я думал что это символ ">"